# How do I make it so that <Input> only allows alphabet, whitespace and backspace?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a 15 by 15 matrix in the form of a html table and in each cell there is an input box. I want it so that the user can only:

- type english letter
- delete a character (backspace)
- Use spacebar
- And later on, I want them to be able to use arrow keys to navigate the matrix

So far the code below allows me to check if it's an english letter or not, but I cannot use backspace, spacebar nor can I update the cell.

The following is my code for the matrix and how I update the value:

```
  const matrix = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    const row = [];
    for(let j = 0; j< 15; j++){
      row.push("")
    }
    matrix.push(row)
  }
  const [board,setBoard] = useState(matrix);
  const handleBoardChange = (event,row,col) => {
    if((event.target.value.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && 
    event.target.value.charCodeAt(0) <= 90) || 
    event.target.value.charCodeAt(0) === 32 ||
    (event.target.value.charCodeAt(0) >= 97 && 
    event.target.value.charCodeAt(0) <= 122))
    {
      let copy = [...board]
      copy[row][col] = event.target.value
      setBoard(copy)}
    }
  return (
    <div className="analysis-section">
      <Board 
        board={board}
        handleBoardChange ={handleBoardChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the matrix itself:

```
const Board = ({board,handleBoardChange}) => {
  let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      let rowID = `row${i}`
      let cell = []
      for (var idx = 0; idx < 15; idx++){
        let cellID = `cell${i}-${idx}`
        let row = `${i}`
        let col = `${idx}`
        cell.push(
        <td key={cellID} id={cellID}>
          <div>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              maxLength="1" 
              value = {board[parseInt(row)][parseInt(col)]}
              onChange = {(e) => {
              handleBoardChange(e,parseInt(row),parseInt(col))}
              }
            >
            </input>
          </div>
        </td>)
      }
      rows.push(<tr key={i} id={rowID}>{cell}</tr>)
    }
  return (
    <div className="board">
      <table>
        {rows}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Board
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function would prevent accepting letters other than the English alphabet, and it also allows backspace and space bar, as well as arrow keys.

```
 const onChange = (e) => {
let value = e.target.value;

value = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z _]/gi, "");
setValue(value);
};
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-varahamihira-j8l1k?file=/src/App.js:134-264)

Comment: It works, thank you so much. Do you know how I can integrate the left arrow function to navigate the table?